# Container header bar width won't go 100% with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I set the width of .header to width:100% but it doesn't cover the ends of the screen only close to it. I'm using twitter bootstrap's grid to create this site.
Here's what it looks like http://andrewhnovak.com/newSite/index.html

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Site Demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/header.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mainPage.css">


</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="header">
 <div class='col-md-1'>
 Logo
 </div><!--end header container-->
 <div class='col-md-2 col-md-offset-1'>
 <div class='link1'>
 <a href="#">Link1</a>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class='col-md-3'>
  <div class='link2'>
<a href="#">Link2</a>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class='col-md-2'>
 <div class='link3'>
<a href="#">Link3</a>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class='col-md-2'>
 <div class='searchBar'>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Box">
 </div>
</div>
<div class='col-md-1'>
<div class='searchButton'>
<button class="btn btn-search" type="submit">Search</button>
</div>
</div>

</div>

</div>

<div class="container">
<div class='underHeader'>
{{outlet}}
</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class='whiteBox'>
<div class='newProducts'>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>

<script src="js/jquery.easing-1.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/handlebars-v2.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/ember-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Relevant CSS Code

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.header {
    background-color: black;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 14px;
    color: white;
}

.searchBar {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 6px;
    width: 200px;
    right: 21px;
}

.searchButton {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 6px;
}

.underHeader {
    background-color: green;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Change the padding left and right of class container to 0
.container{
padding-left:0;
padding-right:0}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because body has a default margin. Set it to 0 and it will work.

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change `class="container"` into `container-fluid` and remove `width:100%` in class header